# Delphi XE8 Adding .pas from another project

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Quick question for anyone who is proficient with Delphi XE8. I need to add a .pas file from another project into my current project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Open the Project Manager.
2. Find the name of the desired Project.
3. Right click on the Project and select "Add...".
4. Select the `.pas` file in the search dialog.

This will link the file to the project.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I normally hate it when some one edits my post.  But I have to admit you improved it. :-)

Comment: You need to do something about that attitude. It's not your post. As soon as you post it, it becomes the property of Stack Exchange. It's now in the hands of the community. If we make it better, you should be pleased. @Remy regularly edits my answers to improve them, for which I am very grateful.

Comment: IMO, it is his answer. He conceived it, wrote it down, and his name is under it, not the name of one of the StackExchange owners. It may legally be the property of SE, but it is his post. I see nothing wrong with his attitude. It is his baby alright.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, especially when I was acknowledging that he improved it !!!  David, just being pedantic, assuming SO is hosted in USA, with the current law, the US Government owns every upload. :-)

Comment: @Ken: I merely objected to "It's not your post". Yes, it still is, no matter the legalese. Just like if I put my code in the public domain, it is still my code, even if others can modify and use it as much as they like.

Comment: @Rudy: Read the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal), particularly the second sentence in the first paragraph of Section 3.

Comment: @Ken. I know the "legalese" and the terms of service. It is still his post (even if legally, it may not be), because he wrote it and his name is under it. It is presented and thus visible to the world as his answer, not someone else's. FWIW, Embarcadero has very similar terms of service, in this respect. But when I modified (improved) a single message by removing an expletive, I got a sh*tstorm of reactions, because people do see their posts as, well, their posts even if legally, they are not.

Comment: @Rudy You do frequently seem to struggle to understand this site. You seem to feel that if the site doesn't work the way that you feel it should, that these conventions and norms don't apply to you, because you don't want them to. This site is not the same as the Embarcadero forums. It has different standards and norms.

Comment: I understand this site pretty well, thank you. I do think the site does work the way it should. That does not mean I always fully agree with how others, be they old-timers or newcomers, **think** the site should work. -- I am, BTW, not even talking about how this site works. I am merely saying that the answer he posted is, morally and perceptively, his answer, and no one else's, and it has his name under it and he conceived an posted it, even if *legally and structurally*, this may not be so.

Comment: In other words: this time, I am not talking about how the site works or should work at all. I am merely saying that, since he wrote the answer, and since his name is under it, it is presented as his answer, and I'm sure that you would call all the answers with your name under it your answer. I've often enough seen you use "my answer" in comments. Well, in that same sense, his answer is his answer, even if legally, it is owned by SE now.

Comment: One other comment: I do fully understand the rules. I just don't always agree with the, er, *unwritten* rules of this site, the subjective interpretation of the written rules that some seem to regard law.

Comment: And the reason for the minus vote is.